# Cannot override mutable property 'refreshControl' of type 'UIRefreshControl?' with covariant type 'UIRefreshControl'

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

I use a `UIRefreshControl` in my tableview for pull new data. But when I define the control, below error shows. I've googled for a while, but find nothing useful.

*I use Xcode Version 9.2 (9C40b), swift4, IOS11.2*

> Cannot override mutable property 'refreshControl' of type
>   'UIRefreshControl?' with covariant type 'UIRefreshControl'

```
var refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
```

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to define another control, then change the name... `refreshControl` is a `UIScrollView/UITableViewController` ivar since iOS10/iOS6 [respectively]. You're trying to redefine it and that is what causing the error. Or you can use the supplied one of course.

You probably meant something like `self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()`

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4/5

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
    self.refreshControl!.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: "Pull to refresh")
    self.refreshControl!.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refresh(sender:)), for: UIControl.Event.valueChanged)

}

@objc func refresh(sender:AnyObject) {
   // Code to refresh table view

    self.refreshControl!.endRefreshing()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is preventing you from specifying a more stringent requirement in your subclass than the one set by your superclass.

Suppose the compiler allowed you to override an `Optional` property with a non-`Optional` type. What happens if someone does this:

```
let tableView: UITableView = CoolTableViewSubclass()
tableView.refreshControl = nil // but my overridden property can't be nil!
```

As a subclass, you need to work ok when someone treats you as if you were your superclass. So the compiler stops you in this case because it can already tell that you're breaking this rule.

[Mike Ash wrote this up in an unsurprisingly good post if you're curious.](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2015-11-20-covariance-and-contravariance.html)